# Taking photo and video on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im trying to be able to take and capture a photo and show it in a uiimage view AND/OR take a capture a video and play it back in a movieplayercontroller.

I am able to click a button and "Take Photo" which does display in my uiimageview just fine.  However the image disappears out of the uiimageview if i click a button to "Take Video"  The take video works and displays back fine but like a said my uiimage has now disappeared.

If i go back to re take the photo the video i captured disappears?

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface addEventViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    UIImage *eventPhoto;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

}

-(IBAction)TakePhoto;
- (IBAction)takeVideo:(id)sender;
@property (copy,   nonatomic) NSURL *movieURL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *movieController;



@end
```

.m file

```
#import "addEventViewController.h"

@interface addEventViewController (){

}

@end

@implementation addEventViewController


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    // FOR THE TAKE PHOTO
    eventPhoto = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage: eventPhoto];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    // FOR THE TAKE VIDEO
    self.movieURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


}


-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{

    //FOR THE TAKE PHOTO
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    // FOR THE TAKE VIDEO
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// TAKE PHOTO BUTTON
-(IBAction)TakePhoto{
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [imagePicker setSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController: imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}

// TAKE VIDEO BUTTON
- (IBAction)takeVideo:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}



- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    [self.movieController setContentURL:self.movieURL];
    [self.movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (420, 76, 320, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.movieController.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.movieController];

    [self.movieController play];

}

- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];



}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually compiled and run your code, but looking at it, you're defining `imagePicker` in the class instance, whereas you're defining `picker` inside the `TakePhoto` method. My guess is that when you run through the process, the method instance is being destroyed once it completes.

Instead, try using a single imagePicker instance declared at the class level, set its properties differently depending on whether the user is loading an image or video, and set the selected media accordingly.